# I'm looking for birth or baptismal record Westensee, Germany

Tags: germany, birth-records, 1850s

My great grandfather, Ludwig August Adolph Ehlers, 1854–1942
BIRTH 19 SEP 1854 • Westensee, Rendsburg-Eckernförde, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany
Arrived in USA in 1894 in New York.  Sailed out of Hamburg on ship 'Dania'.  Last known residence was Neumünster, Rendsburg-Eckernförde, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany
He might have gone by Louie Ehlers as well.  Trying to find birth documents, with parents names on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a Census for 1855 on [FamilySearch](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/501834?availability=Family%20History%20Library) (39481) for - among others - Westensee and Neumünster available.